# How to highlight CSHTML in Jekyll/Pygments

Tags: jekyll, pygments

I'm using Pygments for highlighting code snippets in Jekyll.

I want to know how to highlight .cshtml/.aspx files using Pygments highlighter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here are the available lexers](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/) in Pygments. Since ASPX might contain C# or VB, it should be supported in Pygments since it is on the [supported languages list](http://pygments.org/languages/).

The relevant ones that you are looking for would be `aspx-cs` and `aspx-vb`, as those highlight ASPX code snippets.

```
{% highlight aspx-cs %}

   //your aspx code here 

{% endhighlight %}
```

Or if those `aspx` code snippets mainly contain static html or `xhtml`, you should be able to just `{% highlight html %}`.

CSHTML should probably just use `csharp` or `c#` as the short name.

A readable reference list of languages and their shortnames [are found here](http://haisum.github.io/2014/11/07/jekyll-pygments-supported-highlighters/).